# Configuring root directory internal ASP.NET server

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008

My ASP.NET always starts like this with the internal server:
http://localhost:50793/Website/

I use FckEditor which points to http://localhost:50793/fckeditor

How do I configure the server that it servers my folder "Website" as the root?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When it comes to anything 'Microsoft Administrative', TechNet is usually the best place to look.  This [ASP.net Administrator Guide](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc787030.aspx) is probably a great place to start.

Comment: Cheers, I'll just go and read everything that Microsoft wrote on the subject. I'm sure the answer will be in there somewhere :)

Answer (score 0):

Go click on the website project in the solution explorer, then edit the "Virtual path" in the properties window.

Comment: Note that this is in the properties panel, not the project's Property Pages. Step by step instructions here: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/12/19/tip-trick-how-to-run-a-root-site-with-the-local-web-server-using-vs-2005-sp1.aspx